# Using the main google maps page (not the API) in order to geocode an address

Tags: python, google-maps, geocoding

Is there a way (using python) to use maps.google.com in order to get LatLng of an address?

(the API doesn't support Israel, but the main page does)

I tried using geopy but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where do you see LatLng in the page of an address ? I typed 'New York' and I see nothing.

Comment: @eyquem You have to right-click and drop a marker, then it shows. Also the LatLng appears inside the url of the "link" button (upper right side of the page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Israel it's possible to use waze.co.il instead of google:

Their JSON API is

http://www.waze.co.il/WAS/mozi?q=yourAddress&token=yourToken

(Also, as stated in this thread http://www.waze.co.il/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=6113 reverse geocoding is a paid service.)